# How can I prevent Unity from wiping per-platform quality defaults after a build?

Tags: unity, build-process

I set up my per-platform quality defaults as follows before a build:

[image: Before build]

However, Unity wipes them out after a build. This causes the quality defaults to go back to "Very Low":

[image: After build]

The build turns out fine. However, this is an annoyance that can accidentally be checked into the source control by oversight and cause the later builds to have different quality settings.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

I am using Unity 2020.3.17f1.

Comment: This looks to me like a bug to report to the Unity devs.

Comment: @DMGregory You might be right, I will post this on the Unity forums also to see if it is indeed a bug or the intended behaviour.

Comment: If the QualitySettings.asset is not a file that you change all that often, then you could in theory make it read-only and try it that way as a workaround.